# How to find the Facebook ID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When i go to `http://graph.facebook.com/harshamv` i get the following error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (harshamv)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

Is there any way i get get my Facebook ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need global IDs anymore, only App Scoped IDs. You get them by authorizing a user with no additional permissions and a call to the `/me` endpoint.

More about the change can be found in the changelog:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

More information about the same error message:

- [Facebook - "Cannot query users by their username" solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886468/facebook-cannot-query-users-by-their-username-solution)
- [Social framework returns "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (username)" when trying to get user feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615961/social-framework-returns-803-cannot-query-users-by-their-username-username)
- [Facebook Graph API v2.1: getting user id and his posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258670/facebook-graph-api-v2-1-getting-user-id-and-his-posts)